# Element value not showing up in console when set via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, console

I am slightly confused about this.

Why the value attribute of #edit does not change in the console?

Am I missing something?

```
<div class="editor">
    <form>
        <input id="edit" value="" type="text">
        <input id="key" value="" type="hidden">
        <input value="Save" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<ul>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-1">Value 1</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-2">Value 2</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-3">Value 3</span> </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $( "*", document.body ).click(function( event ) {

        event.stopPropagation();

        var edit    = $('#edit');
        var key     = $('#key');

        var id      = this.id;
        var content = this.html();

        if ( id.substring(0,2) == "__") {

            console.log(this.id);
            console.log(content);

            edit.val(content);
            key.val(id);
        }

    });

</script>
```

UPDATE...

After much unrelated discussion than ks to @charlietfl I came to a demonstrable difference as presented here https://jsfiddle.net/n4pe07j6/1/

Comment: Why using this reference, when you have $(this) in jQuery?

Comment: Because using the native DOM `this` is cheaper, and in quite a few cases simpler, than using jQuery's `$(this)` and its methods.

Comment: move importantly why do you have a global click event.? you want this to happen no matter where someone clicks? you declare id  and then use this.id in the log why? also "this" is very unclear in example.... ie would this not depend on what you clicked on or is it document.body.

Comment: @Seabizkit - Because I have to determine which element is clicked when it is clicked and it can be anywhere in the document and doesn't have to follow any particular pattern. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Will throw lots of errors since not all elements have id and many elements have no innerHTML. Also would make far more sense to just bind one handler to `document` and use the event target

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to target ID's with `__` at the beginning it is really expensive to add a click handler to every element in the DOM.

Use a single delegated click handler with a selector that targets those elements.

```
 $(document).on('click', '[id^="__"]', function(e){

     $('#edit').val($(this).html());
     $('#key').val(this.id)

});
```

EDIT: the attribute value of an input is not the relevant value that gets submitted by the form. There is a difference between the *value attribute* of a form control and the *value property* of that element. It is the value property that gets submitted

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9yph3jf9/)**</kbd>

Comment: Would you have any idea as to why the value attribute of #edit does not change in the console?

Comment: create a demo that replicates it. No reason it shouldn't

Comment: Here's the fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/n4pe07j6/ if you inspect elements you'll see that value attribute of element with id #edit doesn't change. I am trying to understand why?

Comment: attributes are different than properties. You won't ever see an input value attribute updated in the html, the property is updated

Comment: so hidden element value is considered a property?

Comment: no, value is the property. It does seem that browsers do update the hidden value though...never noticed that before. Likely to help devs troubleshoot

Comment: if you do `$('input').attr('value', 123)` it won't submit that, it's the value property that needs to be set

Comment: but there is no need to do that ...form will submit the property value, attribute is meaningless. It's only needed on page load to tell browser if there is a value to assign to the property

Comment: yes, yes,, I know and I have a working solution,, so that was not an issue at all.. I simply have some stuff to do with this code and while I was reviewing it I noticed this console behavior... Otherwise I am researching suitable and inexpensive ways to detect elements when they are interacted with and manipulate them without affecting the html templates inline and for now I didn't even make any decisions on what path to take.. I am just fiddling with stuff.. So thanks for the inputs and thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many better ways to write this, but as you are just starting out why not do something like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeValue(elem){
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var id      = $elem.attr("id");
        var content = $elem.html();
        $('#edit').val(content);
        $('#key').val(id);
    }
</script>

<div class="editor">
    <form>
        <input id="edit" value="" type="text">
        <input id="key" value="" type="hidden">
        <input value="Save" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<ul>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-1" onclick="changeValue(this)">Value 1</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-2" onclick="changeValue(this)">Value 2</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-3" onclick="changeValue(this)">Value 3</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't have the option to bind anything to html - onclick="changeValue(this)" ... I have to determine which element is clicked when it is clicked and it can be anywhere in the document and doesn't have to follow any particular pattern

Comment: what do you mean? your not allowed to use on-click in the html? is this a business requirement? as from a coding prospective you defiantly can... what do you mean bind... your invoking a javascript function.

Comment: why would you even want to use inline script? This is 2015, not 1999

Comment: I asked a question about jQuery relating to values being displayed in the console. What I am doing is unrelated matter really. In short I have a dynamic situation and I am not in position to start hard coding JavaScript into HTML templates. What I am required to do has to rely on detection across any given document and has to be adaptable to unforeseen situations. What I posted here is a small sample of a few approaches that I'm considering. I appreciate that you are looking into this from your unique perspective but when I asked if you had a suggestion I refereed to on click detection.

Comment: @charlietfl lets not go there... but agreeded.

Comment: @GRowing yes yes.... but part of the problem is that the code is not very well written... so I was trying to give you an easier way. the code you have I would consider **bad practice** and is more error prone due to it being a **global scope** of the click watch event and **inconsistent interpretation of what "this"** , so why the value is not showing up in console... I'm surprised its working at all.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is: "var content = this.html();" is not valid. There is no .html() on a javascript element, .html() is from the JQuery lib and such it needs to be an JQuery element so, "var content = $(this).html();"  makes it work. I think that is what you are after then taking it from all your other comments.

Comment: what do you see in element inspector here https://jsfiddle.net/n4pe07j6/ Is it just me or the value on one element in the form gets updated but not on the other element

Comment: I believe this is what you are after: Uncaught TypeError: this.html is not a function

Comment: In the given fiddle??

Comment: hope cozs that fiddle is update and corrected code... I was answering why your code in the question did not work. Which is what you asked after charlietfi has provided an answer and others had also answered and tried to  help you.

Comment: thanks for all the insights.. here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n4pe07j6/1/

Answer (score 0):

or even this.

```
<form>
        <input id="edit" value="" type="text">
        <input id="key" value="" type="hidden">
        <input value="Save" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<ul>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-1">Value 1</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-2">Value 2</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="cursor" id="__optin-3">Value 3</span> </li>
</ul>

    $('.cursor').click(function( event ) {
        $('#edit').val($(this).html());
        $('#key').val($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Kumar,, I managed to demonstrate the problem here https://jsfiddle.net/n4pe07j6/1/

Answer (score -1):

Just replace 'this' keyword with $(this) and user .attr('id') instead of .id and you are good to go.

Comment: Um.. there is still no change to value attribute in console